# Angular braces notation for types resulted by javap

Tags: java, javap

In java profiler command output, I've been seeing these notations in angular braces like

```
java.util.Queue<E>
java.util.TreeMap<K, V>
```

Correct me if I'm wrong; working through some exercises, I've been able to relate E-Entity, K,V - Key-Value pair. I've seen others like `java.lang.Iterable<T>`, for which I couldn't figure out what T is for.

Can someone help me in telling what these notations are called and how many such exist in Java SE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They’re called generics. They allow a method/class/interface etc. to operate on multiple types of Object (e.g. Integer, String) without compromising type checking.

See:

- https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java
- https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/juneau-generics-2255374.html

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about a aspect of the java programming language called *generics*
[You can read more about them here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_generics.htm)

The letters used don't actually matter. As you said, in the `java.util.TreeMap<K, V>` interface, the letters 'K' and 'V' were used, probably because they are the first letters in the words "key" and "value", **but any other letters could have been used.** Java does not care what letters you use when defining a generic class or interface, that part is all up to you.